# no software with cfbundleidentifier of '%1$@' exists

Tags: ios, xcode

I have bundle identifier i created in iTunes connect which is com.tyler.imdowntagsios and I put that same bundle identifier in the project file as well as in my plist file but I get an error when trying to deploy that says `no software with cfbundleidentifier of '%1$@' exists`
why is the bundle identifier in the error not the same as the one I entered?

Answer (score 0):

In the find navigator, if you do a search for text containing '%1$@' in your project, it should show where in your plist or xcodeproj this unexpected bundle identifier is coming from.

Comment: it comes up with no results found

Comment: I know you said you created the bundle identifier in iTunes connect but to clarify, did you 1) create the bundle identifier on developer.apple.com and 2) add a new app on iTunesConnect and pick that bundle identifier from the dropdown?

Comment: yeh its for an existing app on the app store and I am trying to do a prerelease beta through test flight

Comment: I see, ok. Under your project's build settings, can you try selecting your distribution certificate under Code Signing Identity for Release, and try selecting your app's distribution provisioning profile under Provisioning Profile for Release?